# program of multiplying large numbers, perform until loop not working in cobol

Tags: cobol

The code works fine when I do perform calculation x times. however the multiplier is not changing when I do it this way. I'm new to COBOL so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I basically want a while loop that works until multiplier is greater than 0. Since cobol doesn't have recursion, I'm trying it this way, it works fine in C, however it's giving me issues in terms of the loop here.

```
identification division.
program-id. multiplication.

data division.

working-storage section.
01 multiplier picture 9(36).
01 multiplicand picture 9(36).
01 answer picture 9(36).

procedure division.
begin.
    display 'multiplier?'.
    accept multiplier.
    display 'multiplicand?'.
    accept multiplicand.
    perform calculation
        with test after
        until multiplier > 0.
    display answer.

calculation.
    if ((function mod(multiplier, 2)) = 1) then
        add multiplicand to answer
    end-if.
    divide 2 into multiplier.
    multiply 2 by multiplicand.
```

Comment: Until multiplier > 0? Don't you mean while multiplier > 0?

Comment: yes, sorry while. should I be using while?

Comment: Either that or "until multiplier <= 0". It's been 30 years since I used COBOL on the old IBM mainframe.

Comment: Where are you initializing answer?

Comment: There is no while in Cobol, just Until (unless they have changed this recently). You could use until multiplier = 0 as you have defined the variables as pic 9 so they can never be negative. If the compiler supports comp for 36 digit numbers, try adding comp or even better comp-5

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using GnuCOBOL (or an older OpenCOBOL, GnuCOBOL is the new name for OpenCOBOL). The 2002 COBOL Standard (superceded now by the 2014 Standard) introduced recursion to COBOL (IS RECURSIVE on the PROGRAM-ID), and GnuCOBOL supports recursion, and it is quite common amongst other COBOL compilers.

That aside, why use recursion for something when there is a non-tortuous alternative?

You have three actual problems, two covered in the comments on your question already.

UNTIL. This means "until this condition exists, keep doing the PERFORM". It can be located at the "top" of the iteration (the first thing) or at the bottom (the last thing). Once the condition is true, the PERFORM will not execute. Whether the PERFORM ever executes when the condition is initially true depends on WITH TEST. WITH TEST BEFORE (the default) means that the PERFORM will not execute at all if the condition is true when the PERFORM is encountered. WITH TEST AFTER delays the test until the first execution of the code-block (for an inline PERFORM) or paragrap(s)/SECTION is complete.

multiplier is already greater than zero when the PERFORM is encountered. You use WITH TEST AFTER, so you get one shot to change the termination value. The code does nothing to make sure that multiplier is not greater than zero, so the PERFORMed paragraph will not be entered again as the termination condition is true.

Use EQUAL TO ZERO, ditch the WITH TEST AFTER. multiplier cannot be negative, and it has no decimal part. When one is divided by two and the result stored, that result will be zero. This will surely and certainly happen each and every single time in your program. It is your termination condition.

You have defined answer, and use it as the target of an addition, but it has no guaranteed value before the addition. Set it to zero (VALUE clause, or MOVE ZERO TO ... or INITIALIZE ...) before using it as the target of a calculation of any type. However, don't give it an initial value if it does not need one.

If the first time `something` is used is like this:

```
ADD x TO something
```

Then you should ensure it has an initial value. If it is like this:

```
MOVE x TO something
```

Then an initial value is just a confusion, unnecessary, never needed, as nothing will ever notice it has that initial value.

GnuCOBOL will/can give defined storage initial values depending on data-type. This is not necessarily portable to other COBOL compilers, so it should not be relied upon. The explicit initialisation, only when needed, also indicates to future readers that you know what you are doing.

You have forgotten to end your program. Because you have forgotten to end it, control just runs on, arriving in your `calculation` paragraph one last time, before finally dropping off the end of your program. GnuCOBOL has no real problem with that, but again that behaviour is non-portable, and you're only lucky that the code which is dropped into changes nothing when it is executed at that stage of the program.

Other than that, I'd recommend avoiding unnecessary full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION. Having error-checking on your input. Using better names. Your multiplier and multiplicand are initially that, but is that a good and clear thing to call them throughout the program?

Here's your program with only the required full-stops/periods in the PROCEDURE DIVISION, initialisation and the termination condition corrected.

```
   identification division. 
   program-id. multiplication. 
   data division. 
   working-storage section. 
   01 multiplier picture 9(36). 
   01 multiplicand picture 9(36). 
   01 answer picture 9(36) VALUE ZERO. 
   procedure division. 
       display 'multiplier?' 
       accept multiplier 
       display 'multiplicand?' 
       accept multiplicand 
       perform calculation 
           until multiplier = 0 
       display answer 
       goback (or stop run or exit program) 
       . 

   calculation. 
       if ((function mod(multiplier, 2)) = 1) then
           add multiplicand to answer 
       end-if 
       divide 2 into multiplier 
       multiply 2 by multiplicand 
       .
```

Comment: Question without notice: Is there a max length for a 9s-field in GNUCobol or is the old 9(18) still enforced (with implications of compiler-dependency for the current question.)

Comment: @Magoo GnuCOBOL can do 36 digits. IBM can do 31 by compiler option, by Language Extension to the 85 Standard. The current Standard is 31. For portability, 18 would perhaps be more reliable, although I'd guess many if not all compilers would allow 31. I'm not sure when a maximum of 18 wouldn't be enough :-)